# Rotate a .stl file around a specific axis in Qt Qml

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to rotate my stl. file in the screen in x,y,z dimensions. My whole main.qml code is here:

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("3D Viewer")

    header: ToolBar
    {
        ToolButton
        {
            text: "Open 3D Model"
            onPressed:
            {
                fileDialog.open()
            }
        }
    }

    FileDialog
    {
        id: fileDialog
        onAccepted:
        {
            sceneLoader.source = fileDialog.fileUrl
        }
    }

    Scene3D
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        aspects: ["input", "logic"]
        cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio

        Entity
        {
            id: sceneRoot

            Camera
            {
                id: camera
                projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
                fieldOfView: 90
                aspectRatio: 16/9
                nearPlane : 0.1
                farPlane : 100.0
                position: Qt.vector3d( 0.0,-40.0, 10.0 )
                upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
                viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 10.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
            }

            OrbitCameraController
            {
                camera: camera
            }

            components: [
                RenderSettings
                {
                    activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer
                    {
                        clearColor: Qt.rgba(0.0,1, 1, 1)
                        camera: camera
                    }
                },
                InputSettings
                {
                }
            ]

            Entity
            {
                id: satEntity
                components: [
                    SceneLoader
                    {
                        id: sceneLoader
                    }
                ]

                Transform {
                    id: satTransform
                    scale: 0.3
                    rotation: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
                    translation: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 1)
                    rotationX: 0
                    rotationY: 0
                    rotationZ: 0

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But its rotation doesn't change even I change the rotationX, rotationY, and rotationZ. Moreover there is no error it works but it always in the same position. It is basic but I don't know where I fail. [image: Its position]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem and I share it for one who may see the same problem in the future.

```
ApplicationWindow
  {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("3D Viewer")

header: ToolBar
{
    ToolButton
    {
        text: "Open 3D Model"
        onPressed:
        {
            fileDialog.open()
        }
    }
}

FileDialog
{
    id: fileDialog
    onAccepted:
    {
        sceneLoader.source = fileDialog.fileUrl
    }
}

Scene3D
{
    anchors.fill: parent

    aspects: ["input", "logic"]
    cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio

    Entity
    {
        id: sceneRoot

        Camera
        {
            id: camera
            projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
            fieldOfView: 90
            aspectRatio: 16/9
            nearPlane : 0.1
            farPlane : 100.0
            position: Qt.vector3d( 0.0,-40.0, 10.0 )
            upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
            viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 10.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
        }

        OrbitCameraController
        {
            camera: camera
        }

        components: [
            RenderSettings
            {
                activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer
                {
                    clearColor: Qt.rgba(0.0,1, 1, 1)
                    camera: camera
                }
            },
            InputSettings
            {
            }
        ]

        Entity
        {
            id: satEntity
            components: [
                SceneLoader
                {
                    id: sceneLoader
                },

            Transform {
                id: satTransform
                rotationX: 0 //you can type whatever you want.
                rotationY: 0 //you can type whatever you want.
                rotationZ: 0 //you can type whatever you want.
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

}